# Nodejs run exe from full path | child_process

Tags: node.js, child-process

I have to start an exe file with the full path of the game.

I have tried many combination command, the main goal is to exec the full path like this cause i have to iterate many different games.

```
var rainbow = "D:\\Games\\Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six Siege\\rainbowsix.exe"
child_process.exec(rainbow);
```

I know i can start the game in this way:

```
var path = "D:\\Games\\Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six Siege\\"; 

child_process.exec('rainbowsix.exe', {cwd: path});
```

But i have to run it only with the full path.

Thanks for any help:D

Comment: I extract the path from a json, and the path is without \\, but i can make a workaround and have the \\. It isonly an example:D

Comment: I edited the question, the problem is the same, the game don't start.

Comment: What happens when you set the `cwd` properly in the first call?

Comment: The problem is that i cannot set the cwd cause i have only the path, i should split the gamepath and retreive the game folder and the exe. I was wondering if there is a way to do it with only the full path

Comment: Not if the exe expects to be started with it's current working directory in a certain place (which seems to be what's going on here). Use the `path` module to split the path into directory and file ([see](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_dirname_path)) and then use the second approach.

Comment: Ok i think it works but it don't read the full path, breaks at the first space in the file directory. Console log (of the dir) gives: D:\Games

Comment: Thanks. I managed it to work

Comment: Post your solution as an answer below. This way you can close the thread, get an upvote and maybe help out someone else at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Tomalak said in the commets, i had to use the path module, so i splitted the dir and the name of the game.
And than i had to add `'\\\\'` at the end of the line.

```
var dirgame = path.dirname(id)+'\\\\';
var namegame = path.basename(id);
child_process.exec(namegame, {cwd: dirgame});
```

Comment: I don't think you need to add `\\\\\` at the end, that doesn't make sense. What happens if you don't do that?

Comment: If i don't add it, the game won't start

Comment: That's... odd. What happens if you only use a single escaped backslash? Like ` + '\\'`

Comment: Yes, is strange, it took me a long time to discover it, cause i also thought it was wrong, but the game start only if i add  '\\\\' exactly 4

Answer (score 1):

You should go to the disk & game_path & game_name.exe (using exec of child_process).

Example:

```
let link = "e: & cd E:\GAMES\INSTALLED\Fable The Lost Chapters & Fable.exe"
let process = child_process.exec(link, function (err, data) {
    console.log(err)
    console.log(data.toString());
});
```